# Using more Threads for reading the same file in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, ios-multithreading

How can I read a file in Java using multithreading?
It doesn't matter if it's slower than using once, I have to do it.
So, for example, if there are 2 threads, the first reads the first line and, at the same time, the second reads the second line; then the first reads the third line and the second reads the fourth line and they continue reading in this way since the end of the file. How can I implement this in Java?

Comment: You'd need to set up a sequence, so that the next thread won't start till the last thread has completed, unless your file support random access

Comment: And if I use a binary file, so it supports random access?

Comment: Then, in theory, you can use `seek` from something like [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to position the read pointer to where ever you want. But, you'll probably find that each `Thread` will need to open the file within it's own context

Comment: And there isn't a way to read simultaneously with 2 threads a txt file?

Comment: Not really, as most input methods are single directional, even if each thread had it's own reader/stream, it'd have to loop over the first `n` lines until it reached the line it wants to read, which is just pointless

Comment: looks like a homework

Comment: _Why_ do you need to do it.  Can you explain the requirements?  So far my guess is a pointless threaded programming assignment where the teacher doesn't get the point of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a single `BufferedReader` that is shared between the threads, and synchronize on it when calling `readLine()`.

It is completely pointless.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why my teacher gave me this exercise. I thought it was pointless, and you've confirmed it.